# How to correctly create grayscale bitmap without alpha channel on ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, core-graphics

I am trying to create a simple UIImage, 8x1, with gray color space and without alpha channel. My code:

```
- (UIImage *)createImage {
    size_t w = 8;
    size_t h = 1;

    size_t size = w * h;
    uint8_t * buf = calloc(size, sizeof(uint8_t));

    for(int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        buf[x] = (uint8_t) (x * 32);
    }

    CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(buf, w, h, 8, w * sizeof(uint8_t), space, kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaNone);
    CGImageRef img = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(space);
    UIImage * ret = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: img];
    CGImageRelease(img);

    free(buf);

    return ret;
}
```

When I display this image, it looks like this:

[image: result]

No matter the size of the image, the (N-4)-th pixel's colors is replicated to pixels N-3, N-2 and N-1. (the last one should be white)

When I add alpha channel (16 bits per pixel) or use RGB or indexed color model, its ok, but with this bitmap setting, I cannot set colors of the last 3 pixels. Some ghosts are messing with my pixels. Any ideas? :)

Comment: Your code works fine for me in a test app. (I put the `UIImage` in a `UIImageView` to display it, and also used `UIImagePNGRepresentation` to create a PNG file that I opened in Preview.)  How exactly are you displaying the image?

Comment: You are right, it is displayed correctly that way (right pixel is bright white). But when I use:

    -(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
        UIImage * img = [self createImage];
        [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 128, 128)];
    }

I get the last 4 pixels gray.

Comment: I figured it out - I have to use:

[img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 128, 128) blendMode: kCGBlendModeMultiply alpha: 1.0f];

The default blend mode is not suitable for that somehow.

Comment: Interesting, I can reproduce that when drawing in the view. Looks like a CoreGraphics bug to me. By the way, it looks fine on a real device, only wrong in the simulator.

Comment: Thank you for helping me :) On my iphone 5s i looks bad too, btw. Maybe its fixed on newer devices...